# Permission denied for LESS compiler

Tags: less, impresspages

I am trying to modify the header section layout the Air theme and I get the following error:

> Error: file_put_contents(/var/www/ip417/Theme/Air/assets/theme.css): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/ip417/Ip/Internal/Design/LessCompiler.php:174{"result":true,"id":null}

I am using 4.0.17 which I installed today.

I just went back to my 4.0.16 set up where I was doing similar adjustments and I don't get this problem

Comment: Are you sure the compiler is allowed to write in /vart/www/ip417/Theme/Air/assets ?

Comment: I wish I knew, I am new to LESS

Comment: I've just tested on my localhost and on shared hosting. Cannot reproduce this error. Check whether this path really exists and has required permissions to write to that folder/file. It doesn't relate with LESS. It's just PHP cannot write information to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in command line:

chmod -R 777 /var/www/ip417/Theme